# how to count number of items in repeated values?

Tags: scala, playframework

I got a repeated values which are sent from controller. I used it like it in view like this:

```
<select name="subcategory">
@repeat(data("sub_categories")) { i =>
    <option value="@i("id").value">@i("name").value</option>
}
</select>
```

Now I want to count to get number of items in `data("sub_categories")` How can I do that?

I tried `data("sub_categories").length` or `data("sub_categories").value.length`, both do not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is a [Form](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Form) and `data("sub_categories")` is of type [Field](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.data.Field) so for a repeated item you should be able to get number of items by calling `data("sub_categories").indexes.length`